# dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor

Tags: python, torch, feature-selection

This code

```
def forward(self, data):
    x = data.features
    
    yyy=pd.read_csv("ycornell.csv",header=None)
    vectorr=pd.read_csv("vectorcornell.csv",header=None)
    centralityy=pd.read_csv("cornellcentrality.csv",header=None)
    selectedfeaturess= SelectKBest(chi2, k=100).fit_transform(x,yyy)
    x = np.c_[centralityy, selectedfeaturess]
    x= tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
    adj = data.adj
    x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout, training=self.training)
    x = F.relu(self.gc1(x, adj), return_dict=False)
    x = F.dropout(x, p=self.dropout, training=self.training)
    x = self.gc2(x, adj)
    return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

was working fine when i were using x= data.features but when i applied feature selection on x using selectKBest,  have the error

```
dropout(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the input as a pytorch tensor(torch.tensor). Tensors in tensorflow and pytorch are different.

and this part in forward method:

```py
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
```

should change like this.

```py
x = torch.tensor(x)
```